# Natural sort with qsort not working

Tags: c, qsort

I am trying to sort an array of vertexes, the program I need to make is to color vertexes from different graphs, in order to do so more efficiently we use different orders to run greedy, my problem is when i try to order them in ascending order, I'm using qsort() and for some reason it doesn't work on some graphs and I can't understand why, I will leave below the structure of the vertex, the comparison function and also the function I'm using to check the array is sorted.
The vertex are being compared by the name (nombre in spanish)

Typedefs:

```
typedef uint32_t u32; /* Definición de tipo u32 */
typedef struct _Vertice_t *PVertice;
typedef struct _Grafo_t *Grafo;
```

Vertex:

```
/* Definición de Estructura Vertice */
struct _Vertice_t {
    u32 nombre; /* Nombre real del vértice */
    u32 grado; /* Grado del vértice */
    u32 color; /* Color del vértice  */
    u32 index; /* Indice */
        u32 mem_vecinos;
        u32 tag;
        bool visitado;/*variable para saber el numero de componentes conexas*/
        u32 x_aleatorio;/* u32 para uso exclusivo en funcion orden aleatorio */
        u32 aleatorio; /* u32 para uso exclusivo en funcion orden aleatorio */
    u32 cant_de_colores; //uso exclusivo para orden bloque  == 1
    PVertice *vecinos; /* Vecinos del vértice */
};
```

Graph:

```
/* Definición de Estructura Grafo */
struct _Grafo_t {
    u32 nro_vertices; /* Cantidad de vértices del Grafo */
    u32 nro_lados; /* Cantidad de lados del Grafo */
    u32 nro_colores; /* Cantidad de colores usados para colorear el Grafo */
    PVertice vertices; /* Arreglo de Vértices del Grafo */
        bool *facil_busqueda;
    PVertice *orden; /* Arreglo indicador del orden de los vértices del Grafo*/
};
```

Comparison function:

```
int cmpfunc (const void * a, const void * b) {
    PVertice vertice_1 = *(PVertice*)a;
    PVertice vertice_2 = *(PVertice*)b;
  int resultado = ( vertice_1->nombre )-(vertice_2->nombre);
    return resultado;
}
```

Sorting:

```
void OrdenNatural(Grafo G) {
    qsort(G->orden, G->nro_vertices, sizeof(PVertice), cmpfunc);
}
```

Finally how I check it is sorted:

```
bool arrayIsSorted(PVertice *a, u32 n) {
  if ((n == 1) || (n == 0))
    return true;

  if (a[n-1]->nombre < a[n-2]->nombre) {
    printf("%u %u\n", a[n-1]->nombre, a[n-2]->nombre);
    return false;
  }

  return arrayIsSorted(a, n-1);
}
```

The result I get from 1 particular Graph when ran on terminal:

2 4294965727

0

[The Graph](http://www.famaf.unc.edu.ar/~penazzi/Discreta2018/GRD99704280.tar.gz)

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but all symbols starting with an underscore and followed by an upper-case letter (like for example `_Vertice_t`) are reserved in all scopes. Don't use them for your own names and symbols. Also note that the `_t` suffix is usually use for types, not structures.

Comment: More related to your question, what is e.g. `Grafo` and `PVertice`? Please try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show us.

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't include the typedefs I will edit the post

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I do have an array of PVertice, that is orden, in the _Grafo_t structure.

Comment: My favourite method of comparing two numbers `a` and `b` of the same unsigned integer type is something like `(a > b) - (a < b)`. That will give an integer value 1 if `a` is greater than `b`, 0 if `a` is equal to `b`, or -1 if `a` is less than `b` with no problematic conversion of large unsigned values to negative signed values.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Can you convert your comment to answer?

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I'm sorry but I have PVertice *orden and PVertice is a _Vertice_t pointer therefore I have an array of pointers to vertexes, isn't that right? In other words orden is a pointer to an array of pointers, isn't it?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, you're correct. Misread. Then we're back to the need for a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I still think you should use e.g. `sizeof *G->orden` for the element size.

Comment: @IanAbbott Your solution worked fine, could you maybe post it as an answer so I accept it? Also, I really don't understand why my way didn't work, do you think it might have had something to do with the u32 type?

Comment: I usually do something like `if (a < b) {return -1;} else if (a > b) {return 1;} else return 0;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure why your original didn't work assuming `int` is the same size as `int32_t` for your compiler. If your `vertice1->nombre` is less than `vertice2->nombre` then the result of `vertice1->nombre-vertice2->nombre` will be a large unsigned value that is out of range for a 32-bit `int`. Most compilers will just map the out-of-range values to negative numbers although the actual result is implementation-defined.

When subtracting `unsigned int` values, a "negative" difference will end up as a large `unsigned int` value that is out-of-range for an `int`, so the result will be implementation-defined. For a `qsort` or `bsearch` comparison function, only the sign (positive, negative, or zero) of the returned value is used, so an implementation-defined result can be avoided by always returning `-1` for a "negative" difference, `1` for a "positive" difference, or `0` for no difference. There are (at least) three ways to accomplish that :–

1. using `if` statements:

   ```
   if (a > b)
       result = 1;
   else if (a < b)
       result = -1;
   else
       result = 0;
   ```
2. using the conditional operator:

   ```
   result = a > b ? 1 : (a < b ? -1 : 0);
   ```
3. using difference of comparisons:

   ```
   result = (a > b) - (a < b);
   ```

   (this is the "cleverest" of the 3 options, although perhaps not the clearest).

If the `qsort` or `bsearch` wants the values in reverse order then just reverse the order of the variables or reverse the comparison operators.